# Trying to change a background image on page refresh, running into problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

To begin, here is the page.

I've attempted the Javascript code without success, so I will try to explain my current setup.

my body has an ID of #homepage.  This is the only page I will need this code for, so I've assigned that ID.  The following is the CSS to access the image and cover the page:

```
body#homepage {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: url(../images/bg/4.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center bottom; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

There are 4 images in the "../images/bg" folder, numbered 1 through 4.  I simply want the images to change between the 4 upon page load, but I need to keep the images styled as they are in the current CSS.

Since I am only vaguely familiar with Javascript, I believe I'm getting something very simple wrong in the Javascript.  I would appreciate someone spelling this out for me in specific detail.  Thanks so much!

Comment: sorry, here is the page: http://srtmlaw.com/aklZZ25lkenzyq5/index.html

Comment: Please post your relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: Where the js code? And are you looking for 1 of the 4 images to load randomly on page load?

Comment: I didn't submit the Javascript code I was trying to use because I want to know what code is best to use without trying to work from what I was already trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var randomImage = Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1);
var homePage = document.getElementById('homepage');

homePage.style.backgroundImage='url("..\/images\/bg\/'+randomImage+'.jpg")';
```

Comment: Thank you, this is javascript, right?  I'm ignorant about assigning scripts to the head, so do I wrap this in <script type="text/javascript"></script>?

Comment: put this code after footer divs and be shure there is right path, becouse i get this error on your site: http://srtmlaw.com/images/bg/3.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Comment: the path is srtmlaw.com/aklZZ25lkenzyq5/images/bg/3.jpg.  Put the script after the footer?

Comment: yes) after closing the footer div put this javascript, becouse now script fires before the homepage div rendered by browser

Comment: do I change my CSS?  remove the background image property and keep the styles for said background image, or just leave it all the same?

Comment: you can leave your css as is, the script will overwrite it anyway. ifyou leave your css it will work in case JS is disabled.

Comment: Thank you for your help here, hope you have patience for my ignorance.  Could you look at my source code and see what might be the problem?  http://srtmlaw.com/aklZZ25lkenzyq5/index.html

Comment: you issue is with the path. now you point url to http://srtmlaw.com/aklZZ25lkenzyq5/srtmlaw.com/aklZZ25lkenzyq5/images/bg/1.jpg 404 (Not Found)

Comment: use this homePage.style.backgroundImage='url("../aklZZ25lkenzyq5/images/bg/'+randomImage+'.jpg")';

Comment: I guess I'm not understanding the problem with the path.  I've changed it back to the relative path, as originally suggested, and it is not solving the problem.  If I change it to the direct path, that doesn't work either.  This is the direct path: http://srtmlaw.com/aklZZ25lkenzyq5/images/bg/3.jpg  and you can see that the image is there.

Comment: I GOT IT!  Thanks so much.  Not sure what the deal was, but it's fixed.

Comment: Follow up question, if I want to change an associated tag/link with each photo, how would I go about this?  For instance, here is the tag that will need to change: 

<h3><a href="images/photographs/xxx/xxxxxx.html">Description of photo</a></h3>

Answer (score 0):

**with Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var num = getRandomArbitrary(1,4);
$('#homepage').css("background-image",'../images/bg/' + num + '.jpg')
});

function getRandomArbitrary(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

Comment: Not being funny dude, but why use jq for that? There is literally no heavylifting to be done!

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('homepage').style.backgroundImage = 'url(/whatever/img' + Math.floor( Math.random()*4 ) + '.png)';

Comment: Replying on my phone, sorry for the crude example

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get random number from 1 to 4.

I'll show you pure JavaScript and jQuery ways to do it:

## JavaSript way:

```
//get random number from 1 to 4 and assign '.jpg' - or other format you need
var randomImage = "..\/images\/bg\/" + Math.floor((Math.random()*4)+1) + '.jpg';

//get body by ID
var homePageBody = document.getElementById('homepage');

//asign random image to body
homePageBody.style.backgroundImage=randomImage;
```

---

## jQuery way:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var randomImage = '../images/bg/' + randomFromTo(1, 4) + '.jpg';

    //set background to body #homepage
    $('#homepage').css("background-image", randomImage)
});

//define randomizer function
function randomFromTo(rfrom, rto) {
    return Math.random() * (rfrom - rto) + rfrom;
}
```

Comment: You can have functions in pure javascript... Also your "jQuery" way isn't valid, as there's no function called `getRandomArbitrary`